# Javascript swap 2 images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, swap

I'm busy with a project but know I'm stuck at some point. What I want to do is, when someone presses the home button, it changes its color. What I wanted to do is a **swap from image 1 (white) to image 2 (blue)**. So the person can see on which page he/she is.  But when I put this code into the website, it won't show anything. When I press 2 times it will show the blue image. And when I press many times you see the white and blue image swapping. But it won't stand on the white image, only on the blue image

Here is the code I use. -->

```
<a href='' "<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index"); ?>" onclick="edit()"><img id="img1" onclick="imageChange(this)"'<?php echo $sImageURL;?>home.png' alt='<?php $clang->eT("Default administration page");?>' />
<script type="text/javascript">
{
  var img1 = "/LimeSurvey/styles/scanyours/images/home.png";
  var img2 = "/LimeSurvey/styles/scanyours/images/home1.png";
}
{
  var imageChoice = 1;
}
function imageChange(element) 
{
  if (imageChoice == 1)
  {
    element.src = img2;
    imageChoice = 2;
  }
  else if (imageChoice == 2) 
  {
    element.src = img1;
    imageChoice = 1;
  }
}
</script></a>
```

Comment: When you click the home button you're always redirected to the '/admin/survey/sa/index'. That page has the home.png default image. Your javascript updates the image BEFORE you are redirected so that modification will not stay when the page redirects

Comment: So what do you mean? What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Enclosing simple statements (like, without `if`) in `{`…`}` does nothing (useful). ECMAScript implementations do not support block scoping (that way). [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript), STFW.

Comment: There are many ways to solve your problem. With html5 you can use localstorage, or you can use cookies to store the value of the logo color. Upon page load you read this value and update your page with some javascript

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try to not embed the img tag in the anchor tag. Maybe the two onclick events disturb each other.</strike>

By the way: You should indent your code for better clarity.

**EDIT:**

I don't know the exact structure of your website, but if index.php only displays the homepage you could try this:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'index.php') {
  echo 'Show logo for homepage';
} else {
  echo 'Show logo for other pages';
}
```

When it works you could swap the echos with your element.src function. When it doesn't work check what is stored in $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] when you are on your homepage and when you are on a different site and adapt the if statement.

Comment: I just did what you said, but that changed nothing. When I go to the site he doesn't show the button, and only when I click it appears very quickly, and then he opens the page and then its gone. Only when you click more often you see the second image behind the first one

Comment: You should add an initial src attribute to your image. I don't know what is stored in $sImageURL?

Comment: Could you please paste the code what you mean, i come from the Netherlands and the words you use are a bit difficult haha. im sorry ////


$sImageURL? - thats the URL of the image/ the path of the image

Comment: The src="" is missing at your image url ($sImageURL). Thats probably the reason why you don't see it at first.

Comment: You were right, only now I see the white figure, if I click on the blue button it appears for a few seconds and then the white button appears again. he does not stay on the white

Comment: Do you want a blue home logo on the start site and a white one on the other sites? Or do you really want to change it on click?
Because like the others already said, the a tag might redirect you to another page, although the href attribute is emtpy in your code above.

Comment: I want to change it on click, the a tag redirect  it to the home page, i want to change the home buttons color

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2reo4cz/4 :When you dont press. ---------
http://tinypic.com/r/33tp6kl/4 :When you press it goes blue but for 2 seconds

Comment: Alright, your approach is a bit pedestrian. You'd rather do that by checking on which page you are and then set the image the right way. Because like JSantos said the information is lost when you get redirected through your anchor tag. Right now I don't have time to give you example code, but in pseudocode it should look something like this:

if ( page == startPage ) {
    homeLogo = img
} else {
    homeLogo = img2
}

When I get home and you're still stuck I'll give some more detailed code.

Comment: Thanks if thats possible it really will help me out!

Comment: −1. “Embedding” the “img tag” in the “anchor tag” allows for *graceful degradation*. The `click` event on the `img` element must not cause navigation (or something other harmful), so that it can bubble up to the ancestor `a` element; there it needs to be *canceled* (for example, by returning `false`), so that the default action of the `a` element is prevented.  And then it has to be `<a href='<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index"); ?>'`, so that navigation can take place if the `click` event is _not_ canceled (because of missing enabled client-side script support).

Answer (score 1):

If you have your image tag inside an anchor tag then even if your image replacement worked you would instantly be redirected to wherever your anchor links to.

Is that expected behaviour?

```
Here is a working example if you didn't have the anchor tag
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6LZpL/